# How to change the display density in Android Lollipop?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently working on an application for android, and when he migrated from kitkat Android 4.4.4 for Android 5.0.2 lollipop the screen icons were larger and deformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the property "ro.sf.lcd_density", which is in the file "build.prop"

This property will have a default value, and as the screen is with large icons, you'll have to decrease this value.

Ex: If the value is 160, change to 140 and see as it was. If the icons still remain large may decrease again.

I work with android when edicts files on my computer, the file "build.prop" is on the way

Path in Ubuntu Linux: "/media/my_user/SYSTEM/buil.prop"

Remember that to change this file in linux you must be as Root User.

A list of values can be used

Rather than having a specific DPI value for each different device, Android groups displays with similar DPI values together. As such, there are currently 7 different DPIs that Android supports natively:

120 (LDPI)
160 (MDPI)
213 (TVDPI)
240 (HDPI)
360 (XHDPI)
480 (XXHDPI)
640(XXXHDPI)

Font:
http://gs5.wonderhowto.com/how-to/fit-more-content-your-screen-by-changing-pixel-density-your-android-device-0156943/

Comment: I have rooted Android 4.4.2, but changing from 640 to 340 seemed to not change anything. Do I have to reboot the phone for changes to take effect?